# Entity Framework Save returning error with DateTime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime

I have a weird issue with EF 6 when trying to save an entity which has a property of `DateTime` datatype.

I have a form where the user inputs the needed values to the properties of the entity, although, since I don't need to specify all them via the front-end a couple of items are being set before the save.

So, here's my model:

```
public partial class delivery_deviation
{
    public int delivery_deviation_id { get; set; }
    public System.Guid customer_id { get; set; }
    public byte week_nr { get; set; }
    public short year { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime created_date { get; set; }
    public System.Guid created_user { get; set; }

    public virtual sf_ec_customer sf_ec_customer { get; set; }
}
```

This is the action in my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "delivery_deviation_id,customer_id,week_nr,year")] delivery_deviation dd)
    {
        var identity = ClaimsManager.GetCurrentIdentity();
        var userId = identity.UserId;

        dd.created_user = userId;
        dd.created_date = DateTime.Now;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.delivery_deviation.Add(dd);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.customer_id = new SelectList(db.sf_ec_customer, "id", "profile_provider", dd.customer_id);
        return View(dd);
    }
```

I can clearly see that the `created_date` value is not null (see the screenshot) but upon save I always get an exception with the following `InnerException` message:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'created_date', table 'CMS_DEV.dbo.delivery_deviation'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

[image: Object Detail]

Also, here's a screenshot of my table:

[image]

So, what is wrong with my code? Neither I or anyone in the office sees anything wrong with this code.

Thanks you,
Best Regards

#### EDIT

Here's another screenshot where I've noticed the objects signature are different, but I think that's normal:

[image: Exception Objects List]

Comment: Catch `DbUpdateException` exception and see entities there instead on `Add` method. It can be another entity, not `dd`.

Comment: Try adding some code (before calling SaveChanges) to get all Added entities to see if created_date is actually set ***for all of them***. I doubt that there is some other `dd` outside the code you posted having this issue.

Comment: @Hopeless I've inspected the existing 3 object (the delivery_deviation objects list) and found none with a null or invalid date. And yes, there is no other dd.

Comment: @Denis see my new screenshot. Was that what you were referring to regarding being another entity?

Comment: Add logging, like: `DbContext.Database.Log += s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);` to see what sql query is executed by EF

Comment: @Zed_Blade it could be another entity. 
Now expand your `delivery_deviation` entity in exception and see `created_date` property. If `created_data` is not null, use `IDbInterceptor` interface - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.data.entity.dbconfiguration.addinterceptor%28v=vs.113%29.aspx to intercept SQL queries.

Comment: Try checking your db for an empty guid in created_user? Possible collision on that although it references the date.

Comment: @Denis I've just noticed something weird.. Although I had already a couple rows on the table they're not being shown on my gridView. I'll start with that

Comment: @gwilliams now that you mention the `created_user` field, should it not be a uniqueIdentified but instead a varchar? Because I will have multiple entries for the same customer

Comment: @Denis, this is the query being generated `{SELECT 
    [Extent1].[delivery_deviation_id] AS [delivery_deviation_id], 
    [Extent1].[customer_id] AS [customer_id], 
    [Extent1].[week_nr] AS [week_nr], 
    [Extent1].[year] AS [year], 
    [Extent1].[created_date] AS [created_date], 
    [Extent1].[created_user] AS [created_user]
    FROM [dbo].[delivery_deviation] AS [Extent1]}`

Comment: Shouldn't it be the userID of the person who did this particular DD? I'd still do a "Guid.NewGuid()" to see if that's whats causing your error before you redesign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that for some reason, when code-first was generated from an existing Database, not all the mappings were being done correctly.

The `created_date` had a property `StoreGeneratedPattern` set to `Computed`. All I did to solve it was, on the edmx file set it to `None`.

Puff, problem solved.